# Visual Studio 2019 unit tests missing in test explorer but show in live unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, test-explorer, live-unit-tests

I have a solution with about 3000 unit tests.  The test appear and run under the "Live Unit Testing" window but under the "Test Explorer" none appear.   They USED to but suddenly no longer appear in that window.   This is Visual Studio 2019 16.9.1

How can I get them to appear and run in the test explorer window?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid on my part. In the Test Explorer window the total tests at the top were over 3000 but no tests appeared below.  This was because I had (at some point) deselected the tests at the top.  Once I clicked on the number at the top the tests magically came back.